The result clause of first conditional possesses would instead of will

He would be skating champion all right, if he really gives all his time to it.

This sentence seems to be having the structure of 1st type of conditionals by having the condition clause in simple present tense. But the result clause shows 'would' (the past form of will that is generally used in 2nd type of conditionals) instead of 'will'. Furthermore, indefinite article 'a' is missing before the noun 'skating champion'. In the end, there is a comma before the result clause while there is the conjunction 'if' to join these two clauses.

It's ungrammatical (if it is intended to mean what it seems it's intended to mean).

Did you write this sentence yourself, or are you quoting someone else?

Sample: He would be skating champion all right, if he really gives all his time to it.

Corrected to conditional (first conditional): He will be a skating champion all right, if he really gives all his time to it. [will future + present tense (apodosis) in if clause (protasis)]

Corrected to Conditional (second conditional aka irrealis): He would be a skating champion all right, if he really gave all his time to it. [would + verb (apodosis) + simple past in if clause (protasis)]


The difference between 1) and 2) is the speaker's desire to make one more probable than other.
See below for a formal explanation for these forms, which do not include what is called zero conditional or past conditional. For learning purposes, this terminology is fine. It is not fine if you plan to be a linguist. You will need more baggage.

3.2. First Conditional "First conditional" or "conditional I" refers to a pattern used in predictive conditional sentences, i.e. those that
concern consequences of a probable future event (see Types of
conditional sentence). In the basic first conditional pattern, the
condition is expressed using the present tense (having future meaning
in this context. in some common fixed expressions or in old-fashioned
or excessively formal The present subjunctive is occasionally found.
for example:If need be, we'll rent a car. see use of the present
subjunctive), and the consequence using the future construction with
will (or shall):
If you make a mistake, someone will let you know. If he asks me, I
will/shall consider his proposal carefully.
The use of present tense
in dependent clauses with future time reference is not confined to
condition clauses; it also occurs in various temporal and relative
clauses (as soon as he arrives; take the first train that comes;
etc.), as described under Uses of English verb forms § Dependent
clauses.
The present tense used in the condition clause may take the form of
the simple present as in the above examples, or the present
progressive, present perfect or present perfect progressive as
appropriate (according to general principles for uses of English verb
forms): [etc]
3.3. Second Conditional "Second conditional" or "conditional II" refers to a pattern used to describe hypothetical, typically
counterfactual situations with a present or future time frame (for
past time frames the third conditional is used). In the normal form of
the second conditional, the condition clause is in the past tense
(although it does not have past meaning. see Use of the past
subjunctive), and the consequence is expressed using the conditional
construction with the auxiliary would:
If I liked parties, I would attend more of them. If it rained
tomorrow, people would dance in the street. The past tense (simple
past or past progressive) of the condition clause is historically the
past subjunctive. In modern English this is identical to the past
indicative, except in the first and third persons singular of the verb
be, where the indicative is was and the subjunctive were; was is
sometimes used as a colloquialism (were otherwise preferred), although
the phrase if I were you is common in colloquial language. For more
details see English subjunctive § Use of the past subjunctive.
If I (he, she, it) were rich, there would be plenty of money available
for this project. If I (he, she, it) were speaking, you would not be
allowed to interrupt like that.

review of conditionals in English
